# What is standard approach to drawing shader-specific objects?

Tags: opengl, plot

I am plotting a function using vertices, colors, normals, and barycentric points but I also wish to include the axes.  However, the axes only require vertices and colors.  I currently have my shaders set up to load normals and barycentric points so that when I attempt to past the axes, I get a warning about "attempt to access out of range vertices" since shader is expecting normals and barycentric points for the axes.

I see three options:

1. Include fake normals and barycentric points for axes,
2. Write separate shader for the axes,
3. Include a conditional in existing shaders to process axes and function differently.

I ask this for future reference when I need to process multiple items.  Do I just write a different shader for each distinct item or keep adding conditionals in one shader?

Comment: Usually, you use different shaders (in their compiled forms). The source code for these shader can either be completely distinct or be generated from common snippets.

Comment: Ok.  I got it.  I created an axes shader program and a function shader program.  Nice learning experience.  Found out I need to distinguish between a shader program and a shader script:  we attach vertex and fragment scripts to a shader program and then use the program to draw.  So in my code I call gl.useProgram(axesShaderProgram) then draw(axes) then I call gl.useProgram(functionShaderProgram) then call draw(function) after I have linked the two kinds of vertex and shader scripts to each program.  Nice!

Comment: Yeah, but don't use the word *script* for shaders ;).